# Javamail attachment missing in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail, email-attachments, pop3

I am currently writing an application that should scan a user's mail for specific attachments and extract them from the email messages.

I use Javamail to connect to the mailbox, retrieve the messages and parse the email content.
When I retrieve a message with one attachment, Javamail gives me a MultiPart object containing 3 Bodyparts: The plain text email message, the html email message and the attachment.

However, if I run the same piece of code inside a Google App Engine environment retrieving the same emailmessage, I only get 2 Bodyparts: The plain text email message and the html email message. The attachment is missing. The attachment contents are available in the raw inputstream, though.

This is the part of code I use to retrieve and parse the messages:

```
Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
for(Message message : messages) {
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(emailSession, message.getInputStream());
    if(msg.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        for(int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + bodyPart.getContentType());
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what is happening here?
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in Google App Engine.

You're reading the same email message from the same email server, right?

Perhaps the attachment is being removed/hidden because of a (potential) virus issue?

If you turn on JavaMail session debugging, what does the debug output show?

Comment: The debug output is exactly the same in both cases. The client authenticates to the server and retrieves the message. It shows the raw message with the Base64-encoded attachment.
How can Javamail behave so differently inside a Google App Engine environment?

Comment: Are you downloading the entire message to the client, or are you using IMAP to download just the attachment when you need it?  Are you reading the attachment using the getInputStream method?  Are you sure you're not getting any exceptions?  Are you using the JavaMail implementation provided by Google?

Comment: I am downloading the entire message using POP3. No exceptions, no attachment. The Base64 encoded attachment is present in the raw InputStream received from the POP3 server, but not in the parsed BodyPart objects. Is Google providing a different implementation of JavaMail, appart from the classes in javax.mail?

Comment: I have no idea what JavaMail classes Google might be providing in App Engine.  Are you including mail.jar in your application?  What do you get if you use msg.writeTo() and write the message to a file that you can examine later?  Is all the data in that file?  I'm not sure why the exact same data would be parsed differently in the two cases, but perhaps there's something wrong with the message data?  Based on the JavaMail debug output, what JavaMail version is being used in each case?